# How to SELECT a drop down list item by value programatically in C# and pass it to integer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
   public DataTable selectcat(int catid)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.connection);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    com.CommandText = "selectcatalog";
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catid", catid);
    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
        dt.Load(dr);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
}
```

then i call the function in dropdownlist event (SelectedIndexChanged)

```
 protected void catselectddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataTable dt;

    DAcatagory obj = new DAcatagory();
    dt = obj.selectcat(catselectddl.SelectedValue);
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
    catnametxt.Text = dr["catname"].ToString();
    catdestxt.Text = dr["catdescription"].ToString();
}
```

but it give me invalid arguments error at `dt = obj.selectcat(catselectddl.SelectedValue);`
PS: the dropdownlist take his display and the value from database

Comment: catselectddl.SelectedValue is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert it to int:

```
dt = obj.selectcat(Convert.ToInt32(catselectddl.SelectedValue));
```

Comment: Sorry so sorry i just notice it, i didn't make dropdownlist postback

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
  dt = obj.selectcat(catselectddl.SelectedValue);
```

with

```
  dt = selectcat(catselectdd1.SelectedValue);
```

and in debuggin mode, also check what the actual value the ddl is sending to the db

and also , if the db is expecting an int as a value convert it to int32 like other answer.

Comment: if i didnot take an object from that class i will not able to use that function